# echo all and entire MySQL Query rows in php without specifically naming each column

Tags: php, mysql

I have

```
$result = "";
if(someCondition)
  $result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table1 WHERE column = '$value' ");
else
  $result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table2 WHERE column = '$value' ");
```

$result could have 0 -> infinity rows returned

Table 1 and Table 2 have different amounts of columns with different names

I want to write 1 generic loop after the above else that will just print out all of the rows. Preferably 1 per line or deliminated.

To clarify, one of the two query calls will fill the $results variable with rows.

I wont know which one fills it at run time so I want to just do a print all contents to screen. Is there a method that does this? is there a fast loop that iterates through all of the rows without explicitly saying the column names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bored enough to answer:

```
$result = "";
if(someCondition){
  $result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table1 WHERE column = '$value' ");
}else{
  $result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table2 WHERE column = '$value' ");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) ) {

foreach($row as $key => $var)
{
    echo $key . ' = ' . $var . '<br />';
}


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solid answer!